# CompileStoryboard build command failed

Tags: ios, xcode-storyboard

The continuous integration job that we run to generate nightly builds of our iOS app runs an xcodebuild command on our project and it failed today with the following output:

The following build commands failed:

CompileStoryboard < Path to the storyboard >

The startling thing is, the project builds fine in the Xcode and runs without any issues. The storyboard which is at the source of this problem, was given by a team member (as it is a part of a different module) and created on a different version of Xcode. The storyboard was included in the project as an existing file (Right click -> Add)

Is there anything I can try differently to make the CI job build successfully?
I have opened the storyboard and it contains a table view with the outlets etc wired properly. Also tried cleaning the project and rebuilding.

Comment: Was the storyboard just referenced or was was it copied to the project, I would suggest removing it and adding it to the project and make sure Copy if necessary is checked.

Comment: I did the latter, added it and made sure it was part of the project

Comment: I'm seeing this even with a storyboard that was created with the same version of Xcode. xcodebuild will fail and issue that message, but retrying usually works. Might be some bug

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check that it's included in “Copy Resources” but **not** in “Compile Sources”. Also check that it doesn't appear twice (those git merges…)

Answer (score 6):

It might happen as older code might be with an older xcode storyboard version. Your new code might have been compiled with new xCode version. Just make slight changes in all storyboards to modify its version number and commit , it might succeed . Worked for me.

Comment: I was using Infer (Facebook's code analysis tool) and when I changed the storyboards in the project to compile with XCode 7.x instead of XCode 8.0, infer was able to build and check for issues in the project. Maybe it'll help someone in the future. Now I need to see if Infer has an update for Xcode8.0.

Answer (score 2):

Double check that the storyboard opens in the proper version of Xcode that you're building the app with. That can be checked in the Xcode's File Inspector from the Utilities pane. If the storyboard opens in Xcode 8/7 but you're using Xcode 7/6 to build the app, you will have to change the 'Opens in' attribute of the storyboard (or do the build with the matching Xcode version). The same relates to the version of command line tools you're using if you use `xcodebuild` (or `fastlane`, which implicitly uses `xcodebuild`) to automate your builds.
The Command Line Tools version can be changed in the Preferences -> Locations pane.

[image]

Comment: When I change this it keeps automatically reverting to the old setting.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue and it was related to the fact that I had declared the built in collection view reusable cell as a custom class before I made an actual custom cell xib, but never unlinked the collection view reusable view from the custom cell class. 
the project built fine and all was A-OK except for the azure devOps pipeline CI build which was giving me the ^^ above error:

** BUILD FAILED **

The following build commands failed:
    CompileStoryboard /Users/*/ProductDetail.storyboard
(1 failure)

##[error]Error: /usr/bin/xcodebuild failed with return code: 65

Answer (score 0):

Ran into something similar because LaunchScreen was compied from a project with a different name. In my case I went directly into `project.pbxproj` and searched for the old name of the project and replaced with the current project name and rebuilt. Worked like charm!